# Spark RDD Block Removed Before Use

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using a Future to perform a blocking operation on an RDD like this:

```
dStreams.foreach(_.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  Future{ writeRDD(rdd) }

})
```

Sometimes I get this error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task creation failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use BlockRDD[820] at actorStream at Tests.scala:149 after its blocks have been removed!
```

It seems like Spark is having trouble knowing when this RDD should be deleted.

Why is this happening and what is the solution?

**Update:**

I think RDDs might be GC'd before they are used.  The only working solution so far involves setting

```
conf.set("spark.streaming.unpersist", "false")
```

And `unpersist()`-ing manually.

Full stack trace in case this is a bug:

```
15/10/12 23:57:23 ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation: Aborting job.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task creation failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use BlockRDD[765] at actorStream at NxCoreSparkTests.scala:168 after its blocks have been removed!
org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.assertValid(BlockRDD.scala:83)
org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.getPreferredLocations(BlockRDD.scala:56)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:250)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1394)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:1405)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:1405)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getPreferredLocs(DAGScheduler.scala:1368)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$16.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:829)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$16.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:827)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:827)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:772)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:757)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1463)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1280)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1268)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1267)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:836)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1463)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:567)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1813)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1826)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ExecutedCommand.doExecute(commands.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$5.apply(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(SQLContext.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(SQLContext.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:197)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:304)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkDbUtil$.writeToParquetByDay(NxCoreSparkTapeReader.scala:210)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:190)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:188)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:188)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$.retry(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:217)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$.retry(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:219)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$.retry(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:219)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$.retry(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:219)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$.retry(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:219)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:188)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:185)
    at vscan.NxCoreSparkGoogleHDFS$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$1.apply(NxCoreSparkTests.scala:185)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use BlockRDD[765] at actorStream at NxCoreSparkTests.scala:168 after its blocks have been removed!
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.assertValid(BlockRDD.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.getPreferredLocations(BlockRDD.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:250)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1394)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:1405)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply$mcVI$sp(DAGScheduler.scala:1405)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1404)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal$2.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1402)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getPreferredLocs(DAGScheduler.scala:1368)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$16.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:829)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$16.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:827)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:827)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:772)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:757)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1463)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1455)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1444)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
15/10/12 23:57:24 ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DynamicPartitionWriterContainer: Job job_201510122357_0000 aborted.
```

Comment: I think you should not be using async ops there, IMHO. Even if your disk writes were blocking, it should not block streaming in data or processing.

Comment: mehmetminanc is correct.  @BAR: Can you share full stack trace?

Comment: @mehmetminanc It definitely blocks for me in local mode with more than enough cores and parallelism.  The next write will not begin until the previous write completes.  When I add a Future, writes execute concurrently.  Maybe you can suggest another approach?

Comment: @BAR [More parallelism or cores won't help, in your case.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/) As far I understand, you want your disk to write faster/more than it is able to. Spark and other stuff aside, this is wrong in a more fundamental sense. Try sampling down your data, e.g. `filter` or `sample`, or get a disk that can handle more throughput. Asyncio is no magic, it won't double disk's write speed.

Comment: @mehmetminanc i stated that to show this is not a starvation issue.  Obviously we have physical limitations, i am not trying to do the impossible here.   If you are looking for a work around answer, then we need to explain why this is blocking before the next write starts.  If that is solved then there is no need for the future.  But still, i want to know *why* a future should not be used there.

Comment: @BAR Sorry for emphasizing on *how* and not *why*. Sadly, I can't really answer that. But intuitively, I always thought that Spark abstracts away all parallelism and concurrency issues, on several layers - i.e. distributed computing, multithreading, and it assumes user application is a good old single-process app. I assumed that after your lambda completes, which is immediate, `BlockManager` thought that it's done with the block and clean it up. My claims have no grounds, obviously. The block is in sort of a *dangling* state in parallelism sense.

Comment: @mehmetminanc no prob.  Your last sentence sums it up i think.  This might just be a bug... Or bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that, before your code inside `writeRDD(rdd)` executes ( since it is in a `Future` ), the rdd ( or the micro-batch RDD ) is already reclaimed by Apache Spark memory-management  or `BlockManager`.

Therefore, this error

`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task creation failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use BlockRDD[820] at actorStream at Tests.scala:149 after its blocks have been removed!`

You can fix this by first collecting the micro-batch collection and then passing it to `writeRDD()` function. Something like this:

```
dStreams.foreach(_.foreachRDD { rdd =>

  val coll = rdd.collect()
  Future{ writeCollection(coll) }

})
```

Comment: of-course `collect` will create a collection and NOT and RDD. Where is what is the error you are getting now ?

Comment: Same error. Nothing changed, which is surprising because collect definitely happens outside of the Future. Maybe its that collect is lazily evaluated so one must do something with it to execute its DAG.  Might be as simple as writing `col1` right after its declaration.

Comment: what if my data set is huge. actually, i m coming across similar issue.  RDD is processed inside foreachPartitionAsync in my case.