# Spark Streaming does not persist information

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata, real-time, spark-streaming

I have created a Spark Streaming script similar to the wordcount one.
The plus is that I want to store all the information in a collection (addedRDD) but after a while an Exception is launched since the block is gone.
Is there a way to keep this cumulative RDD in memory?

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import scala.collection.mutable
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost",9999)
var addedRDD : RDD[String] = sc.emptyRDD[String]

lines.foreachRDD( 
    rdd => {
        addedRDD = addedRDD.union(rdd).cache()
        addedRDD.collect().foreach(println)
    }
)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val pairs = words.map(word => (word, 1))
val wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(_ + _)

wordCounts.print
ssc.start() 
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

The exception raised is the following (it says that the block has been removed):

```
    ERROR scheduler.JobScheduler: Error running job streaming job 1509014590000 ms.0
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task creation failed: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use BlockRDD[86] at socketTextStream at <console>:38 after its blocks have been removed!
org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.assertValid(BlockRDD.scala:83)
org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.getPreferredLocations(BlockRDD.scala:56)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1547)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getPreferredLocs(DAGScheduler.scala:1521)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$15.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:974)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$15.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:972)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:972)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:921)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:861)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1609)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)

        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1433)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1421)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1420)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:981)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:921)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:861)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1609)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1843)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1869)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1940)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
        at $line38.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:47)
        at $line38.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:44)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:661)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:426)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:49)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:224)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:223)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use BlockRDD[86] at socketTextStream at <console>:38 after its blocks have been removed!
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.assertValid(BlockRDD.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.BlockRDD.getPreferredLocations(BlockRDD.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionPartition.preferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.UnionRDD.getPreferredLocations(UnionRDD.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$preferredLocations$2.apply(RDD.scala:257)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.preferredLocations(RDD.scala:256)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$getPreferredLocsInternal(DAGScheduler.scala:1547)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.getPreferredLocs(DAGScheduler.scala:1521)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$15.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:974)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$15.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:972)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.submitMissingTasks(DAGScheduler.scala:972)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$submitStage(DAGScheduler.scala:921)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleJobSubmitted(DAGScheduler.scala:861)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1609)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1601)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1590)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Answer (score 0):

The above error is `OOM(Out Of MemoryException)` because you are storing the `rdd` in memory after addition of some rdd's to the memory the executor will run out of memory Exception, By default `cache()` store that rdd's in memory

check the below option, will help you to store your rdd to `DISK_ONLY` you may also have few options like `MEMORY_AND_DISK,MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER,MEMORY_ONLY,MEMORY_ONLY_SER` each option will suffixed with `_2` means no of copies in DISK OR MEMORY and SER- means Serialization to reduce storage space either in DISK or in Memory

```
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
addedRDD = addedRDD.union(rdd).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
```

Comment: Hi,the exception is not the Out Of Memory unfortunately.I have just edited my question by adding all the stack trace.
In fact the edit of the code as you wrote didn't change the process, it still goes on error

Comment: **Attempted to use BlockRDD[86] at socketTextStream at <console>:38 after its blocks have been removed!** I guess the problem is with streaming try increasing the Timeout here `val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))`

Comment: And have a look at this question same as yours https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077746/spark-rdd-block-removed-before-use and don't forget to try the Updated section